# MVC Multiple DropDownLists from 1 List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

**Background:** I have 4 dropdown lists on my page that all use one List of `SelectListItem` to pull data from. All 4 of these dropdowns will always have the same exact elements in them. Each dropdown has an empty element at the top.

**Problem:** If I do not select an item from the list that renders 2nd, when the page loads the 2nd list automatically selects the item that is selected in the 1st list. This is because (I think) the list has a `SelectListItem` where `Selected = true`, and it just uses that one in the second list.

Is there any way to use one list source for multiple dropdown lists? I don't want to duplicate this list 4 times unless I absolutely have to...

**Code**:

```
//this is the list source
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PossibleItems { get; set; }

//this is the code on my .cshtml page
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem1, Model.PossibleItems)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem2, Model.PossibleItems)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem3, Model.PossibleItems)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem4, Model.PossibleItems)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your list, need to create different SelectList entities for each of the four drop down lists like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem1, 
    new SelectList(Model.PossibleItems, "dataValue", "textValue", Model.SelectedItem1))
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem2, Model.PossibleItems)
    new SelectList(Model.PossibleItems, "dataValue", "textValue", Model.SelectedItem2))
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem3, Model.PossibleItems)
    new SelectList(Model.PossibleItems, "dataValue", "textValue", Model.SelectedItem3))
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem4, Model.PossibleItems)
    new SelectList(Model.PossibleItems, "dataValue", "textValue", Model.SelectedItem4))
```

In this example, "dataValue" and "textValue" are the properties of the SelectListItem object that correspond to your value and text elements of the drop down options.

Comment: While doing that won't hurt anything, it's not required, and isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: 6 years later, you're still saving lives!  
It might be related to the fact that `Model.PossibleItems` is already a collection of `SelectListItem`, the `SelectListItem.Selected` boolean is then shared between those `DropDownListFor`.

Answer (score 5):

2 years ago but for anyone who finds this like I did looking for answers Feussy's comment above is the way to go.  I'll try to explain why and what I found.

Using the OP example above.  A couple conditions must be met in order to see the described behavior.

- x.SelectedItem1 should have a value (say 1).
- x.SelectedItem2 must be NULL.  (if it is not a nullable type and
  just say an INT it will    default to 0 and you won't see the
  behavior)

Put a breakpoint at `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem1, Model.PossibleItems)`

If you look in Model.PossibleItems you will see the list as expected.
Let the code continue to the next line.
Now if you look at Model.PossibleItems you will see that Html.DropDownListFor has modified your selectlist on the Model rather than just using it!  The option for x.SelectedItem1 now has a 'selected' attribute not only in the HTML that goes to the client but in your model as well!
This seems like bad behavior on Html.DropDownListFor but it definitely does it.

Now when you hit `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem2, Model.PossibleItems)`

- If x.SelectedItem2 has a value it will set it and you will be fine
  but....
- If x.SelectedItem2 is null, the second @Html.DropDownListFor just
  seems to take the altered(by the first DropDownListFor) selectlist as
  is and your second drop down will have x.SelectedItem1 selected. 
  (because the selectlist itself was altered)

Feussy's answer works because instead of having one selectList on the model that gets reused it is creating separate selectLists that are generated from some List/IEnumerable on the model that gets reused instead.

So the moral of the story is don't reuse a  selectList with nullable values because Html.DropDownListFor has no problems altering the thing and won't clear out any selected attributes if the value is NULL.

Hope that was clear.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `List<SelectListItem>`, use a `SelectList`. Then you can reuse the list of items in `DropDownListFor`.

**Model:**

```
public SelectList PossibleItems { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
model.PossibleItems = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item1, Model.PossibleItems)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item2, Model.PossibleItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you currently have is the best way to do it, and it *should* work just as it is. `SelectListItem` does have a `Selected` property, but this is most usually set by a `SelectList` instance. Otherwise, you'd have to manually set this property somewhere on your own. Since you're using `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead of an instantiated `SelectList`, all of the items should default to having `Selected` as false. It's only when Razor renders the `DropDownListFor` control does you enumerable get turned into an actual `SelectList` and have its selected value set based on the model. Check your other code and make sure you're not setting the selected status manually anywhere.

FWIW, you don't need to add an empty item manually: the `DropDownListFor` control has a means to add an empty item to the list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem1, Model.PossibleItems, string.Empty)
```

Comment: I'm not setting the selected value anywhere else, and the solution I have above was not working so I went with seperate lists for each dropdown. Unfortunately its not the cleanest solution, but it's working for now.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I agree that it should work. But @gwin003 is right. Something is wrong here. See [this question on asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1902801.aspx?DropDownListFor+modifying+passed+SelectListItems) and [this question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844121/multiple-dropdowns-from-one-selectlist-asp-net-mvc?rq=1) for unsatisfactory responses.

Comment: The only thing I can think of a possible cause is that the conversion of `Model.PossibleItems` into a true blue `SelectList` is perhaps being cached and used for each drop down, since they all use the same thing. What happens if you just duplicate the drop down choices into another property and use that for one of the drop downs? Does the same behavior occur?