# DropDown List selections in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a loop to create multi `DropDownList` in the same view. As a result of the loop, two lists are created. However the problem is when user select an item from one list, the other list will change its selection to be the same selection from the other one.
So, how do I avoid that, and make selection process separated from a list to another?
Here is the code generate the list

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedDays", listItems, new { @class = "form-control", id="Day"+item.id })
```

EDIT:
The ListItem Code is this

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{

    Text = "1 day",
    Value = "1"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{

    Text = "3 days",
    Value = "3"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Selected = true,
    Text = "7 days",
    Value = "7"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{

    Text = "15 days",
    Value = "15"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{

    Text = "30 days",
    Value = "30"
});
```

and This is the loop

```
@{
foreach (var item in companyList)
{
<div class="panel-body">

                                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Admin/Telecom" method="post">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Payment View</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                                                        @Html.DropDownList("selectedDays", listItems, new { @class = "form-control", id="Day"+item.id })
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                        <button type="submit" name="btnView" value="@item.TelecomCompanyName" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded w-md waves-effect waves-light m-b-5">change</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>


                                    </div>
}
```

Comment: Provide the code for the entire loop.

Comment: it is too large, do we need that?? @RacilHilan

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you do. First of all a *too large* loop by itself is an indication of bad code. Anyway, you don't need to post it all, just post the lines related to the list and the loop line. We need to find why the too lists are linked.

Comment: are you sure each list item is having different id's

Comment: Did you mean to create one form with two lists? Because your code is creating two forms with one list each. If that's what you want, then fine, otherwise you have to take the code for the form out of the loop. and if this is the entire look, it's not too bad :-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reuse `listItems` between DropDownLists. After selecting a value on one list, element will be `Selected` on all of them. Create separate lists for each DropDownList.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work @borkovski

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880662/mvc-multiple-dropdownlists-from-1-listselectlistitem Maybe it'll match your case.

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically generating more dropdownlists with the same id.
They should have different ids to behave correctly.

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedDays" + item.id, listItems, new { @class = "form-control", id="Day"+item.id })
```